# Can DisplayPort enhance resolution?

Tags: resolution, external-display, displayport

I'm a little new to the gaming laptop scene and I've been wondering:

If I bought a laptop with a native resolution of 1920x1080 and hooked up a DisplayPort cable to an external monitor, would the monitor be able to produce more resolution? Or would it simply transfer the 1920x1080 onto the larger screen?

Comment: It would be capable of whatever the native resolution of the external screen.  However, if you get a 4k monitor the frame rates may be unacceptably low while gaming.  You need to also look at the max your video card can produce but you need to tell us what kind of video card this laptop has or look it up yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The external monitor would only be able to display up to it's maximum resolution. If that resolution is greater than that of the laptop (sizes above 1920x1080 are still a bit uncommon), you could have your laptop display at the larger resolution (or choose to mirror the laptops current resolution).

The cable itself does not particularly matter. A DisplayPort or Dual-Link DVI cable are both capable of displaying any resolution you would encounter on a commercial monitor

Answer (score 0):

Most laptops are capable of displaying higher resolution than their native resolution when connected to an external monitor; at least that has been my experience.  You should be able to display anything up to the monitor's native resolution but not beyond that, though as cybernard pointed out, the refresh rate may be unacceptable.